# Target all elements before match in jQuery each loop

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I want to disable all radio buttons in a set which are before the matched element in an each function. But somehow I can't target them correctly.

I think the best way would be if I could do something like "target all elements that were processed in this each function until now". But as I couldn't find anything like this I want to try it per traversing but I can't get to target them as well this way.

My HTML:

```
<div class="chooseTime">
    Bitte wählen Sie ihre gewünschte Lieferzeit.
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" checked="" value="06:00 Uhr - 10:00 Uhr" name="chooseTime">
        06:00 Uhr - 10:00 Uhr
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="10:00 Uhr - 14:00 Uhr" name="chooseTime">
       10:00 Uhr - 14:00 Uhr
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="15:00 Uhr - 17:00 Uhr" name="chooseTime">
        15:00 Uhr - 17:00 Uhr
    </label>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
if($('#Picked_date').val() == $('#Fast').data('lzp_date')) {
    var lzp_time = $('#Fast').data('lzp_time');

    $('.chooseTime input[type=radio]').each(function() {
        var wert = $(this).val();
        if(wert == lzp_time) {
            $(this).prevAll('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(this).parent().prevAll('.radio').find('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled', true);
```